# Repeat characters X times but do not count Y characters that are in between (Regex)

Tags: regex

I need a regex that does the following:

- Repeat any number x amount of times
- Ignore characters and do not count them (example: whitespace and '/')

This is the regex I have right now:  `[0-9]{0,5}`

However, it does not cover the following legit strings:

```
1 2 3 4 5
123/45
1234 5
1 234 4
1/234/5
1/234 5
1 2/3 4/5
1     2345
1 ////23/////45
```

I tried:

```
[\s*\/*0-9]{0,5} //counts unwanted characters
[0-9\s\/]{0,5} //counts unwanted characters
[0-9-\s+\/]{0,5} //counts unwanted characters
[\s+\/-]{0,}[0-9]{0,5} // does not mix
```

Is this even possible in regex?

The other solution, I can do is to remove these characters and then comparing to the pattern.

Comment: You can't discard any chars within a single matching operation. Match (to consume) all the chars (e.g. with `\d(?:[ \/]+\d){0,4}`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nkvu8E/1/)), and then post-process

Comment: What about this one: `(?:[ \/]*\d[ \/]*){0,5}` It matches 0 to 5 numbers that are each surrounded by zero or more other legit characters

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. That regex works first try from Manu in my application. I'll look up the documentation again so I fully understand what is going on.

Comment: I added an answer where I quoted Manu, Wiktor had some feedback so I'll add it here for history sake.

'This is a bad pattern since the [ \/]* should not appear at both start and end of the repeated group, it is like asking to match an infinite amount of spaces or slashes twice. Two times infinity will lead to issues once the pattern is used in some context, or when anchored.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you can use is

```
(?:[ \/]*\d){0,5}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nkvu8E/2). *Details*:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[ \/]*` - zero or more spaces or slashes
  - `\d` - a digit
- `){0,5}`  - end of the group, match zero to five times.

If you need to match any spaces or slashes *after* the last digit, add `[ \/]*` at the end:

```js
(?:[ \/]*\d){0,5}[ \/]*
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand why the other suggestion has a flaw. This also works for my application. I'll use this.